# unable to git log after copiing a repo

Tags: git, copy, repository

Each time I copy a git repository from one machine to another either through a tarball or a s3 cloud storage, I can not anymore `git log` on the copied repo.

```bash
git log 
FRX: No such file or directory
-FRXS: No such file or directory
```

```bash
 ls .git/logs/
HEAD  refs
```

However commands like `git branch` or `git checkout` work.

Can someone explain to me why ?
Thanks.

Comment: I guess you have missing metadata..... the _standard_ way to do that would be by cloning or bundling.

Comment: `FRX` and `-FRXS` are options for program `less`. Please look into `echo $LESS`, `git var GIT_PAGER`, `git config --list --show-origin` to see how `less` is (mis)configured.

Comment: Thanks @phd, I feel silly, long time I did not work on my own repos and it's the same.  
Actually `echo $LESS` returns nothing, `git var GIT_PAGER` gives `less $LESS -FRXS`, and `git config --list --show-origin` `FRX: No such file or directory
-FRXS: No such file or directory`. The issues comes from my shell. How can I fixe this ?

Comment: @Éric Looks good. Though I usually set `PAGER` to just `less` (no options) and `LESS` to `FRSX`. But that most probably shouldn't matter.

Comment: @phd, export LESS=-R does the trick. Thanks for your help.